# Replace snare with powershell, pushing event logs

Tags: powershell, wmi

Is there a way to use powershell to push event logs to a SIEM?  I have this that we can 'GET' event logs but we are looking for an 'agentless' way to push logs to a ElasticStack/Arcsight SIEM.

We have this that we can 'Get' event logs-

```
#$cred = Get-Credential
#$events = Get-WinEvent -Computer localhost -Credential $cred -FilterHashtable @{logname="Security"; id=4688} -MaxEvents 25
$events = Get-WinEvent -Computer localhost -FilterHashtable @{logname="Security"; id=4688} -MaxEvents 20
 #$eventXML = [xml]$events[0].ToXml()  # This was for Testing
 #$eventXML.Event.EventData.Data       # This was for Testing
$outputcol = @()
ForEach ($Event in $Events ) {
$eventXML = [xml]$Event.ToXml() 
if ($eventXML.Event.EventData.Data[8].'#text' -like "*") {
  $output = New-Object PSobject
  $output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Time -value $Event.TimeCreated
  $output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Event -value $Event.ID
  $output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Computer -Value $Event.MachineName
  #$output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Computer $eventXML.Event.EventData.Data[1].'#text'  #Computer
  $output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Command $eventXML.Event.EventData.Data[8].'#text'  #CommandLine
  $outputcol += $output
}  
} 
$outputcol | Format-table -auto | Tee-Object "C:\Users\eventlogs.txt"
```

But is there a way to set this through AD or WMI?  We are trying to avoid installing yet another agent on workstations.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

OK didn't want to leave this blank or delete in case someone else comes looking... it looks like this is possible -- from a post in spiceworks thanks to David Auth

Two GPOs will get you done, son! For rolling up into $3rdparty_SIEM, I created one subscription each for App into the local App log, Sys into the local Sys log, and Sec into Forwarded Events, because... Windows?. Then one GPO for the collector and one for the source, both defining and enabling the Windows Event Log Collector service (y'don't say!), then the IP filter, and add Network Service to Restricted Groups in order to grab the Sec logs. Simple enough!

...if I find out anymore or gotchas, I'll post it here.